# Subdivision surface creates thorn-like artifact/curve (Blender 2.8)

Tags: modeling

I'm using blender 2.8 and this issue occurred while I was retopologizing something using the poly build tool.

Subdivision surface is create a weird thorn-like curve and I can't figure out why. My unmodified mesh looks fine.

Let me just show you the images because its probably hard to figure out what I'm saying through text alone. I lack the knowledge to accurately describe what I'm seeing here.

Image with subsurf:
[image]

Image without subsurf:
[image]

Normals (definitely hard to see, but they're all pointing the same direction):
[image]

UPDATE: So I solved the issue, but I still don't know what caused it. 
I selected the whole mesh, and `deleted loose`. That gave me a face with 6 vertices. Creating an edge by selecting the two middle vertices and pressing `f` recreated the issue; However, using the knife tool to cut the new face solved the issue. I somebody knows what this means, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: you must have an edge inside, please share your original file

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue, but I still don't know what caused it. I selected the whole mesh, and deleted loose. That gave me a face with 6 vertices. Creating an edge by selecting the two middle vertices and pressing f recreated the issue; However, using the knife tool to cut the new face solved the issue. I somebody knows what this means, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to know what cause it, please share your blend file with problematic part via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com as moonbots asked. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In cases like these it always comes back to some type of bad topology: overlapping, non-manifod etc. Do a mesh cleanup. Alternatively delete the problem area and grid-fill it back.